# I'm trying to make a food ordering app in android studio but unfortunately it crashes on startup in emulator either in real hardware

Tags: java, android

Probably the issue is that it need some dependencie what i forgot to include.
What it can do is to show to show a menu bar, and some foods, but when i open it crashes, no matter what i do.

**This is the logcat of the real hardware:**

```
2019-11-19 22:51:18.441 2236-2236/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.doinanenishoppja, PID: 2236
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.doinanenishoppja/com.example.doinanenishoppja.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3003)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3064)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1659)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
```

**And this is some other calls what the Constructor.java called:**

```
   `at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.example.doinanenishoppja.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6977)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3064)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1659)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 1 to color: type=0x5
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:480)
    at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.parseAttrs(FButton.java:116)
    at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.<init>(FButton.java:52)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.example.doinanenishoppja.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6977) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3064) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1659) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)`
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)`
```

Comment: Do you have some code related to an array of color ? (Look at the **Caused by** in your error)

Comment: Are you using ViewPagerIndicator by chance?

Comment: Post your gradle build file

Comment: Post your MainActivity + the layout it's inflating. It's failing to inflate this widget in your layout: info.hoang8f.widget.FButton

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 1 to color: type=0x5 <<<<<<This is your problem but without code it's hard to tell where you made a mistake...

Comment: Corrected logs formatting to clear visibility.

Comment: Hey guys! Thanks for your anwers. First, i have a color array, second, yes i use a viewpageindicator, third, the gradle build: